# Javascript array of objects where an object also contains an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I am new to Javascript and programming in general, I hope someone can help me.

I am trying to create a model where drugs distribute throughout the body in different compartments/organs. A compartment has an inflow of drug and an outflow of drug from another compartment.

I want to create a variable called body which contains an array of objects aka different compartments/organs which I can access the various parameters.

I can create the following

```
 var mybody = 
[
    {ID:"1", fullname:"Arterial", inflowID:"0", outflowID:"2"},
    {ID:"2", fullname:"Kidney",   inflowID:"1", outflowID:"3"},
    {ID:"3", fullname:"Vein",     inflowID:"2", outflowID:"0"},
];
```

What I am trying to achieve is inflowID needs to be array of size 2, inflowID[0], inflowID[1], inflowID[2].

the following syntax dosnt work but you can see what I am trying to achieve

```
{ID:"1", fullname:"Arterial", inflowID[0]:"3", inflowID[1]:"4", inflowID[2]:"nil", outflowID:"2"},
```

I have tried using square, curly and curved brackets in various ways but cant work out what the correct syntax needs to be.

If I need to I can separate this out of my body array.

David

Comment: you're looking for `{ID:"1", fullname:"Arterial", inflowID:["3","4","nil"], outflowID:"2"},` syntax

Comment: can you be specific ? what you want explain properly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An array is build as simple as this:

`[ element 1, element 2, element 3, ... , element n ]`

Which you already got correct for your array of objects.

```
var mybody = [
    {ID:"1", fullname:"Arterial", inflowID:["0", "0", "0"], outflowID:"2"},
    {ID:"2", fullname:"Kidney",   inflowID:["1", "1", "1"], outflowID:"3"},
    {ID:"3", fullname:"Vein",     inflowID:["2", "2", "2"], outflowID:"0"},
];
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you are:

```
{ID:"1", fullname:"Arterial", inflowID:["3","4","nil"], outflowID:"2"}
```

Comment: Thank you for helping me out, it works now, I knew it would be something easy.

Answer (score 0):

try this out it might help you...
sample Example..

```
var mybody = 
    [
        {
             ID:"1", 
             fullname:"Arterial", 
             inflowID:["3","4","nil"], 
             outflowID:"2"
       },
        {
             ID:"2", 
             fullname:"Kidney",   
             inflowID:["2","1","0"], 
             outflowID:"3"
        },
        {
             ID:"3", 
             fullname:"Vein",     
             inflowID:["3","3","0"], 
             outflowID:"0"
       },
    ];
```